# Merging VC runtime into MSI

Tags: windows-installer, merge-module

I'm building an installer package for an application, and would like to merge the **MSM** for the **VC runtime** into it.

Using `Orca`, this works fine and without conflicts.

Using `msimerg`, I get an error code **1629 (ERROR_DATATYPE_MISMATCH)**, but no further information, and no `_MergeErrors` table is generated.

Is there a way I could find out where the error occurs specifically?

Comment: What tool are you using to build your MSI?

Comment: I'm using msidb and makecab, starting from schema.msi.

Comment: You should take a look at using Wix. It is free and open source and will be easier to maintain long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error just means that there is a schema difference between the two databases. The version of msimerg you're using might have a hard-coded schema requirement that could be old if it's an older version of msimerge.exe.

Comment: Indeed. i2 vs i4 on one column, and differing maximum values in the `_Validation` table.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I wouldn't do this.  As I recall, those merge modules introduce issues that impact upgrades.  I would use the vcredist packages from Microsoft instead.  A simple bootstrapper can lay them down and then your MSI down and keep your MSI nice and simple, reliable.